# How do I reduce the speed for this jquery counter animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a counter that animates when a specific percentage is achieved. But the animation speed is bit fast which I want to reduce.

Below is my code.

**The HTML**

```
<div class="progressbar" data-animate="false">
  <div class="circle" data-percent="90">
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.progressbar {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 25px;
}
.circle {
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.circle:after {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    content: "";
    border: 2px solid #fb4f14;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 30px;
}
.circle canvas {
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 2px solid #fb4f14;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.circle div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -20px 0 0 -86px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 31px;
}
.circle strong i {
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 0.6em;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.circle span {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 12px;
}
```

**The JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
function animateElements() {
$('.progressbar').each(function () {
    var elementPos = $(this).offset().top;
    var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
    var percent = $(this).find('.circle').attr('data-percent');
    var percentage = parseInt(percent, 10) / parseInt(100, 10);
    var animate = $(this).data('animate');
    if (elementPos < topOfWindow + $(window).height() - 30 && !animate) {
        $(this).data('animate', true);
        $(this).find('.circle').circleProgress({
            startAngle: -Math.PI / 2,
            value: percent / 100,
            size: 180,
            thickness: 30,
            emptyFill: "rgba(0,0,0, .2)",
            fill: {
                color: '#fb4f14'
            }
        }).on('circle-animation-progress', function (event, progress, stepValue) {
            $(this).find('div').text((stepValue*100).toFixed(1) + "%");
        }).stop();
    }
});
}
animateElements();
$(window).scroll(animateElements);
});
```

**Deployment:**

**[JS Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/bzwxq8v3/3/)**

I tried below code to slow down the speed to my JS file, but it did not work.

```
animateElements();
$(window).scroll(animateElements).animate(slow, 5000);
```

Comment: It would have been much easier if you have mentioned that you are using "circle-progress.js" plugin and read its documentation see  https://github.com/kottenator/jquery-circle-progress#options

Comment: It's in the documentation https://github.com/kottenator/jquery-circle-progress#options

Comment: Thank you guys for pointing to the documentation part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add duration param to circleProgress:

```
circleProgress({
  startAngle: -Math.PI / 2,
  value: percent / 100,
  size: 180,
  thickness: 30,
  emptyFill: "rgba(0,0,0, .2)",
  fill: {
    color: '#fb4f14'
  },
  animation: {
    duration: 3000
  }
})
```

Comment: It might be worth pointing at these 2 bits of documentation https://github.com/kottenator/jquery-circle-progress#options and http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: It works .. Thank you so much .. Upvoted and accepted the answer .. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

I have made the edits in the fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/4osnc1af/

Just need to add duration for the animations to reduce the speed.

```
animation:  {
    duration: 4000
    },
```

Comment: This is the same answer as Rainmx93

Comment: Thanks for the effort . It works. Upvoted your answer. As @Rainmx93 answered correctly first, I accepted his answer. Have a nice day :)

Comment: Thanks @Nitesh :)

Answer (score 1):

you need to add one more property inside your js code (animation:{duration: 3000})

```
$(this).find('.circle').circleProgress({
        startAngle: -Math.PI / 2,
        value: percent / 100,
        size: 180,
        thickness: 30,

        animation:{duration: 3000},

        emptyFill: "rgba(0,0,0, .2)",
        fill: {
            color: '#fb4f14'
        }
```

for more information about circle animation you can visit https://github.com/kottenator/jquery-circle-progress

Comment: This is the same answer as Rainmx93

Comment: Thanks for the effort . It works. Upvoted your answer. As @Rainmx93 answered correctly first, I accepted his answer. Have a nice day :)